# Comparing formatted date displayed in textview to current date in android

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I am making an android app which displays date in textview using simpledateformat. The date can be moved back and forth by using two buttons namely previous and next respectively.

Now the formatted date which is displayed in textview, how do I know whether this date is current or not?

Comment: whenever you change the time, you can compare it with the current date and time in the same format.

Comment: How ? GIve the code to me. I am using below code.

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = formatter.parse(sel_date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                c.setTime(date);
                txt_sel_date.setText(formattedDate);
                String strDate = formatter.format(date);

Comment: @AnoopSharma: please add your code to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the date in text view is current, you can format current time to your date format and compare string with the one in your text view:

```
    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    if (currentDate.equals(txt_sel_date.getText().toString())) {
        // date in text view is current date
    }
```

And if you want to now also if it is before or after current date, you should parse string from text view and compare it with current date:

```
    String textViewString = txt_sel_date.getText().toString();

    try {
        Date textViewDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(textViewString);
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        if (currentDate.after(textViewDate)) {
            // text view date is before today
        } else if (currentDate.before(textViewDate)) {
            // text view date is after today
        } else {
            // text view date is today (currentDate.equals(textViewDate) == true)
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```